# How can I configure the exec-maven-plugin to call two different Shell scripts on Windows - One at the start of the run, and one at the end?

Tags: bash, shell, maven, pom.xml

folks. I am attempting to implement tutorial code that I barely understand. I've got most of it working, but I'm struggling with getting maven to run two shell scripts. For context, I have two shell script in this structure:

```
JavaSeleniumPortfolio
-src
 -main
  -scripts
   -startDockerContainers.sh
   -stopDockerContainers.sh
```

I am on a windows machine with bash installed and linux integration. If I double click the files individually they work like a charm and start or stop my docker containers the way I want them to.

The goal is for the startDockerContainers script to run in the pre-integration-test phase, and the stopDockerContainers script to run in the post-integration-test phase.

Here is a snippet of the POM:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>Start Docker</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>
                    ${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}/startDockerContainers.sh
                </executable>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>Stop Docker</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>
                    ${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}/stopDockerContainers.sh
                </executable>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This HALF works. If I run mvn clean verify, it will start my docker containers, run my test, open the browser, test, close the browser, and then fail with this message:

```
Cannot run program "C:\Users\Me\Documents\GitHub\JavaSeleniumPortfolio\src\main\scripts\stopDockerContainers.sh" (in directory "C:\Users\Me\Documents\GitHub\JavaSeleniumPortfolio"):
```

So it sees the plugin and the pre-integration-test phase and runs the startDockerContainers, but can't see how to handle the stopDockerContainers.

I had read that you could include the configuration block in the individual execution (instead of after executions), so I tried this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>Start Docker</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}/</workingDirectory>
                <executable>
                    startDockerContainers.sh
                </executable>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>Stop Docker</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}</workingDirectory>
                <executable>
                    stopDockerContainers.sh
                </executable>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Which results in this error:

Command execution failed.: Cannot run program "startDockerContainers.sh" (in directory "C:\Users\Me\Documents\GitHub\JavaSeleniumPortfolio\src\main\scripts"):

Even though I know for sure the file is there!

Now I've gotten desperate. I've read several other posts and someone mentioned you need to call bash first (I didn't in my first plugin example up there but whatever, I'll try anything once):

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>Start Docker</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}</workingDirectory>
                <executable>
                    bash
                </executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>startDockerContainers.sh</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>Stop Docker</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}</workingDirectory>
                <executable>
                    bash
                </executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>stopDockerContainers.sh</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

So in this case I have two executables in a single plugin, each of which calls bash before the file. This nets me this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (Start Docker) on project JavaSeleniumPortfolio: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 2 (Exit value: 2) -> [Help 1]
```

Which doesn't even mention the scripts or trying to open bash.